# Get the difference between 2 hours - Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component with start date and end date and i want to achieve exactly the same behavior as in the New/Edit event. So, my purpose is whenever the user changes the end date, i want get the difference between those 2 hours, so that if i change again the start date to automatically change the end date with the respective time. But i cannot find a way to achieve this. Any ideas? Code below: My problem is in the function handleEndChange of controller js Component, where i want to get the difference between end date - start date and then set it to the differenceBetweenDates attribute.
Component

```
<!-- 2020-05-12 @ggalaios This Lightning Component handles the Start Date and End Date as well as Is All Day Event on event record-->

<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" 
                access="global" >

    <!-- Define Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="inputType" type="String" default="datetime"/> <!-- set dynamically the type of the input -->
    <aura:attribute name="startDatetime" type="Date" />
    <aura:attribute name="endDatetime" type="Date" />
    <aura:attribute name="differenceBetweenDates" type="Integer" default="60"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isAllDayEvent" type="Boolean" Default="false" />
    <!-- Handlers Declaration -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <lightning:input type="{!v.inputType}" name="startDateTime" value="{!v.startDatetime}"
                     label="{!$Label.c.Start}" onchange="{!c.handleStartChange}" required="true"/>
    <lightning:input type="{!v.inputType}" name="endDateTime" value="{!v.endDatetime}"
                     label="{!$Label.c.End}" onchange="{!c.handleEndChange}" required="true"/>

    <lightning:input type="toggle" label="{!$Label.c.All_Day_Event}" name="allDayEvent" checked="{!v.isAllDayEvent}"
                     onchange="{!c.allDayEventHandle}"
                     message-toggle-active="{!$Label.c.Yes}"
                     message-toggle-inactive="{!$Label.c.Yes}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(component.get("v.isAllDayEvent"));
        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate.getMinutes() && startDate.setMinutes(60);
        component.set("v.startDatetime", startDate.toISOString());
        console.log(startDate.toISOString());
        var finalDate = new Date();
        finalDate.getMinutes() && finalDate.setMinutes(120);
        component.set("v.endDatetime", finalDate.toISOString());
    },

    handleStartChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var start = component.get("v.startDatetime");
        var d = new Date(start);
        d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() +component.get("v.differenceBetweenDates"));
        component.set("v.endDatetime", d.toISOString());
    },

    handleEndChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var start = component.get("v.startDatetime");
        var end = component.get("v.endDatetime");
        console.log(component.get("v.endDatetime"));
        console.log(end - start);
        var diffMs = (end - start); // milliseconds 
        var diffDays = Math.floor(diffMs / 86400000); // days
        var diffHrs = Math.floor((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000); // hours
        var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
        component.set("v.differenceBetweenDates", diffMins);
        console.log(diffDays + " days, " + diffHrs + " hours, " + diffMins + " minutes ");
    },

    allDayEventHandle: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('handled@!@');
        console.log(component.get("v.isAllDayEvent"));
        if(component.get("v.isAllDayEvent")) {
            component.set("v.inputType", "date")
        } else {
            component.set("v.inputType", "datetime")
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this case 'start' and 'end' strings

please use

```
var diffMs = new Date(end) - new Date(start); // milliseconds
```

thanks

Comment: Thanks very much, Pavel!